# How to configure Webpack?

Tags: javascript, web, npm, webpack, development-environment

I need to compile sass and jade.

I found an option for sass, but it does not work. Compiles only at startup.

I tried these commands:

- webpack-dev-server --watch-poll
- webpack-dev-server
- --watch webpack-dev-server

But it only compiles after such a command:

- webpack

```js
const path = require('path');    
const webpack = require('webpack');    

module.exports = {
               entry: './src/index.js',
               output: {
                   filename: 'main.js',
                   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                   publicPath: '/',
                   sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
               },
               devtool: "source-map",
               devServer: {
                   hot: true, // Tell the dev-server we're using HMR
                   contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                   publicPath: '/'
               },
               module: {
                   loaders: [
                       {
                           test: /\.css$/,
                           loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
                       }, {
                           test: /\.sass$/,
                           loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                       }
                   ]
               }    
};
```

How can I solve my question?

Comment: @CodyG. If you use this command, there will be no update in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your test for `sass` files should work fine to compile from `sass` to `css`. I would suggest first trying to remove the separate test you have for `css`, as your `sass` test should already be compiling to `css` and the additional `css` test may be breaking something.

So try this configuration for your `module` section:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.sass$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```